# Magento 2 - How to get recent month's best seller products?

Tags: magento2, best-seller

I am get bestseller product using below code but it will not display best seller products of latest month, It will display bestseller product from starting.

Can anyone tell me how can I filter best seller product.

Thanks In Advance.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
    $collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

     $collection->setPeriod('month');      

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        print_r($item->getData());
    }
```

In short I want to implement below query logic.

> SELECT * FROM `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` ORDER BY
>   `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`.`id` DESC

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code in your block :

```
namespace RH\HelloWorld\Block;

class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_collectionFactory;
  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
      array $data = []
  ) {
      $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

  public function getBestSellerData(){
    $bestSellerProColl = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setPeriod('month');
    return $bestSellerProColl;
  }
}
```

Use in your phtml like :

```
$bestSellerData = $block->getBestSellerData();

foreach ($bestSellerData as $key => $value) {
  echo "Product Name : ".$value->getProductName()."<br/>";
}
```

***Note : Make sure data available in database.***